# Is there a way to extract specific text from another string in python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I've a column as product description containing a description of the product i.e Kanchivaram saree of red colour. I want to extract just the product type i.e "saree" in this case. Following is an example of the table

| product_description | product_type |
| --- | --- |
| kanchivaram saree of red colour | saree |
| Pink gujrati saree | saree |
| Lehenga from Surat | lehenga |
| Red swim suit | swim suit |

Is there an algorithm or a way I can do that in python.

Comment: sure... but if you already have the product_type for each description why do you need to extract it?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have dataframe`df`as below.

df

```
    product_description
0   kanchivaram saree of red colour
1   Pink gujrati saree
2   Lehenga from Surat
3   Red swim suit
```

You will require list of words as which will contain in column `product_type` as below.

```
lst= ['saree','Lehenga','swim suit']
```

Then `lst` will iterate over each row in column `product_description` and create `product_type` column as below code.
Using Regex -Efficient for Big DataFrames, also it is case insensitive.

```
import pandas as pd 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'product_description': ['kanchivaram saree of red colour', 'Pink gujrati saree', 'Lehenga from Surat', 'Red swim suit'],} 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
lst = ['saree','Lehenga','swim suit']
regex = re.compile(fr"\s*({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in lst)})", re.IGNORECASE)
df['product_type_using_regex'] = df['product_description'].str.extract(regex, '')
df
```

Alertnate Method-(Case Sensitive)
Complete code-

```
import pandas as pd 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'product_description': ['kanchivaram saree of red colour', 'Pink gujrati saree', 'Lehenga from Surat', 'Red swim suit'],} 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
lst = ['saree','Lehenga','swim suit']
df['product_type'] = df['product_description'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join([m for m in lst if m in x])).replace('',np.nan)
df
```

Output-

```
   product_description              product_type
0   kanchivaram saree of red colour saree
1   Pink gujrati saree              saree
2   Lehenga from Surat              Lehenga
3   Red swim suit                   swim suit
```

Comment: Looping and using `in` is certainly an inefficient way to do this, performance will be terrible on large inputs.

Comment: do let us know any other way to improve performance

Comment: You can use a regex for example. See duplicate.

Comment: done updated code using regex & thanks

`regex = re.compile(fr"\s*({'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in lst)})", re.IGNORECASE)
df['product_type_using_regex'] = df['product_description'].str.extract(regex, '')`